# Multiple navbar header for multiple navbar-collapse

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make multiple navbar-header for multiple navbar-collapse. When click navbar-header #1, show first navbar-collapse, then when I click navbar-header #2, show next navbar-collapse.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav id="menu" class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-header"><span class="visible-xs visible-sm">#1</span></div>
  <div class="navbar-header"><span class="visible-xs visible-sm">#2</span></div>
  <div class="navbar-header"><span class="visible-xs visible-sm">#3</span></div>
  <div class="navbar-header"><span class="visible-xs visible-sm">#4</span></div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a class="home_link" title="Home" href="index.php"><span><b>Menu</b></span></a></li>
      <li class="custom-link"><a href="cara-order.html"><strong>Menu</strong></a></li>
      <li class="contact-link"><a href="katalog.html"><strong>Menu</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a class="home_link" title="Home" href="index.php"><span><b>Menu</b></span></a></li>
      <li class="custom-link"><a href="cara-order.html"><strong>Menu</strong></a></li>
      <li class="contact-link"><a href="katalog.html"><strong>Menu</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: *How?* => Depend what you tried so far?

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: *It mean*, you should try yourself then if you faced with any problem, ask here.